# mvc3 code-first error on sqlexpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When using `sqlexpress`

```
<add name="SchoolContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CatomMvc;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get an error

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
>   contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been
>   added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

When I change to

```
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|School.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

It's work but I want to use sqlexpress or sql 2008 that gave the same error.

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework in your project?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085957/entity-framework-error-when-setinitializer-passed-a-strategy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database `CatomMvc` may already exist  in `.\sqlexpress`. 
Try to rename the database to something like `Catomvc_backup` or drop the database, then try again.

Comment: i'm using mysql and this connector has the same problem
so, just rename database

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could use the following within your `Application_Start()`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContext>());
```

This will force the Database to be recreated, but generally during development you should only use:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
```

To allow the Database to be recreated based on changes to your model.

However, neither of these should make it into your production code!

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your `Database.SetInitializer` function is at the top of your `Application_Start` function.

Does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it happens because you dont have sysadmin role on local SQL Server instance. I found useful article where you can download script command and install it. You will be ask for SQLEXPRESS name or instance name, just you can write 'SQLEXPRESS' and enter. Thats it. It will add you to sysadmin role of local server instance.

Download command from: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=addselftosqlsysadmin&DownloadId=9198

Please let me know if it does not work for you.